# Is there a way to globally pad new/delete allocations?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, free, delete-operator

I'd like to implement something like [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_heap_allocations), where native memory is allocated on the Java heap. In order for this to work, I need this subset of the code to work:

```
const static int pad = 16;
void * operator new(size_t t) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
    void* padded = malloc((int) t + pad);
    void* p = static_cast<void *>(static_cast<char *>(padded) + pad);
    std::cout << "new: " << p << " padded " << padded << " size: " << t << std::endl;
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void *p) throw() {
   if (p != 0) {
    void *padded = static_cast<void *>(static_cast<char *>(p) - pad);
    std::cout << "del: " << p << " padded " << padded << std::endl;
    free(padded);
  } else {
    std::cout << "pointer is zero!" << std::endl;
 }
}
```

Where what I'm trying to do is to add some bytes to every memory allocation. This seems to work ok (most deletes are successful), but I'm getting an error:

```
java(379,0x700002206000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc104122180: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Where the stack trace indicated that `free` was called immediately (i.e., not my `delete`) from this line:

```
name = temp.str();
```

Where `name` is a `string`, and `temp` is a `stringstream`. I tried reproducing this error in a non-JNI context, but it didn't crash there.

If I'm padding the memory like this, then clearly it would be wrong to `free` something that had been allocated via `new` or to `delete` something that had been allocated directly from `malloc`. Is that even possible though?

A search for the address in the error in my stdout supports this:

```
new: 0x7fc104122190 padded 0x7fc104122180 size: 32
del: 0x7fc104122190 padded 0x7fc104122180
new: 0x7fc104122180 padded 0x7fc104122170 size: 32
```

where it looks like the address was successfully allocated and then deallocated. The same address appeared again as the unpadded address in the last line printed to stdout (I think it's a coincidence that this address ended up as the unpadded address in the 2nd allocation). But since this is the last line printed to std out, the failed attempt to `free` it is not passing through code I'm seeing (even if I override `free` itself).

Is it possible to get this approach to work? Or must I narrow the scope of my `new`/`delete` to objects that I fully manage myself?

Comment: Just a caution: using C++ streams from inside `operator new` or `operator delete` can run into trouble; sometimes the stream operations use `new` and `delete`, and if that happens everything crashes. C I/O is okay, since it doesn't know anything about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @RawN: That's pretty irrelevant - the whole idea behing overloading `operator new` is to allocate memory from some non-standard source of memory. A "Java heap" sounds like a plausible source.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I get the problem even if I comment my cout lines.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `new()` and `delete()`, there are `new[]()` and `delete[]()` operators. There are some inconsistencies in the standard library when, say, `new()[]` operator is used to allocate an array and then `delete()` used to deallocate it. If you haven't overloaded all four operators, these inconsistency may cause memory allocation errors. Note that in C++17 it will be even more new/delete operators.

Comment: I don't have any inconsistencies of this sort in my source code, however, I can't guarantee that my 3rd party libraries wouldn't do this. Would a compiler introduce it?